# Is there another way of expressing $\sin^{-1}(\cot\theta)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inverse-function

> Is there another way of expressing $\sin^{-1}(\cot\theta)$?

Something similar to, for example, $\sin^{-1}(\cos\theta)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$.

Comment: The relation $\cos \theta = \sin (\pi/2-\theta)$ is an identity; how would you go about translating the graph of $\cot \theta$ into $\sin(a+b\theta)$ for constants $a,b$?

Comment: There is no simpler elementary form.